# MITM the Android emulator

Tags: android, ssl, man-in-the-middle

I am trying to man-in-the-middle the Android emulator so I can decrypt the SSL-traffic with sslsniff. The problem is that the traffic doesn't seem to get routed through sslsniff, even when I have added the iptables rules. `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 999` is the rule I am using for intercepting SSL-traffic, but I don't think it actually sends any traffic to sslsniff. Is there any mumbo-jumbo with the traffic routing when you use the emulator, or anything else I have done wrong?

Comment: If you want anything gui for SSL sniffing, use Fiddler, install the SSL certificate in Fidler's options. http://aurir.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/tutorial-getting-android-emulator-working-with-fiddler-http-proxy-tool/